# How to integrate set of neighboring pixels in raster dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pixel

I generated peaks of tree crowns as an individual pixels from DSM dataset, but there are some trees that have more than 1 peaks. I would like to integrate them based on the threshold value, for example I want to integrate 2 or 3 neighboring pixels that lay in 1 square meters and create one in the middle. I know Integrate tool can do this for vector dataset, but if I convert peaks to vector and re-convert to raster, there is a change in raster dataset which affects further analysis.

Is there any  tool in ArcGIS similar to Integrate which works for raster dataset, or is there any tool to integrate neighboring pixels in any GIS software?

Comment: Perhaps a Con with a Focal Statistics could help group them. I've done this but I used MicroImages TNTmips which allows direct access of individual pixels by ROW, COL addressing which was key to my code. Good luck trying to do this in Esri; It's probably possible but I couldn't find an easy solution working directly with a raster.

Comment: Peaks to points. Integrate and buffer result. Find count of points in each buffer. Remove points sitting inside buffers with more than 1 point. Merge 2 point layers and back to raster

Comment: @FelixIP, thanks for reply, it would be a good solution, but raster to point and back to raster changes the image extend, number of columns and rows (as a result it will not overlap with DSM) which can not be used for grow region segmentation in Saga GIS software. That's why I want to do it in raster dataset directly.

Comment: In arcgis you can set environment Extent, cell size and snap raster. After that you can convert single point to raster with perfect match to original. Surely similar things exist for n saga

Comment: @FelixIP, this was a great solution, thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect collect events is a better tool for weed out job